# Must a class implementing a global interface also be global?

Tags: apex, interface, access-modifier

As stated in the title, when I implement a global interface, do I need to make the implementing class `global`, for example when implementing `Schedulable` or `Database.Batchable<SObject>`?

```
global class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable // valid
public class MySchedule implements Schedulable // valid?
```

Comment: I recollect that when the mechanism was first introduced the class did have to be global but within a couple of versions that mistake was fixed. Whether you make it public or global is now your choice. However, the documentation may not have ever been updated. If you are a managed package creator, a downside of something being global is that it automatically usable outside the package which often is not what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not have to be global:

> The implemented method must be declared as global or public

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

So the reason to use global would be the same as any other class access modifier

> This means the method or variable can be used by any Apex code that
>   has access to the class, not just the Apex code in the same
>   application. This access modifier should be used for any method that
>   needs to be referenced outside of the application, either in the SOAP
>   API or by other Apex code. If you declare a method or variable as
>   global, you must also declare the class that contains it as global

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm

Keeping in mind that the public access modifier is used for:

> The method or variable can be used by any Apex in this application or
>   namespace.

Comment: so, why would you want to make the scheduler class global? what would be a use case?

Comment: SOAP API so you could schedule something using an external tool via the WSDL would be one example

Comment: Another use case:  Want to expose a REST HTTP GET returning a custom Apex Class but you don't want to make the class global.  Create a global interface with no methods, implement that interface on your class, have your global `@HttpGet`'s return type be the interface, and return an instance of your class.